# How can I identify this font or find a good substitute?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

There is this site http://miracle.sega.jp/ It has a lot of embbeded fonts like

"ヒラギノ角ゴ Pro W3",

"Hiragino Kaku Gothic Pro",

メイリオ, Meiryo,

"ＭＳ Ｐゴシック", "MS PGothic",

but I only want the font they used in the buttons. But they are images, not text, so I can't tell which font is. I'd like to find at least a similar font.

Comment: Hi there and welcome to GD! We have some [requirements](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2366) for font identification questions, please take a look and [edit] your question to include that information.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can upload the image here and we can help you find the fonts or you can use the below-given links and upload your image there and find a match.

https://www.fontsquirrel.com/matcherator

https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/